# post_svae Django Signal creates 2 same records in the database instead of one

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-signals

So I am working on a Django Project with DRF.

These are the models
`Tier, Package, PackageDetail, Plan`

Instructions

1. Create a Plan
2. Create a Tier with Tier.plan_id referenced as a foreign key to Plan.
3. Create a Package and include the plan in it.

Now there are 2 possibilities

1. I can just create a `Tier` for a plan without putting that plan in a Package.
2. While Editing a Package I can add more tiers to the the plan in that package.

All of the Package Detail in this table named PackageDetail

```
class PackageDetail(AbstractModel):
    """Package Details Model"""

    package_id = models.ForeignKey(
        Package,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="package_details",
        db_column="package_id",
    )
    tier_id = models.ForeignKey(
        Tier,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        db_column="tier_id",
        related_name="tiers_details",
    )
    details = JSONField()
    tenant_id = models.ForeignKey('Tenant', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, db_column="tenant_id",
                                  null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "package_detail"
```

Now this is what I do

```
class TierCreateView(GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = TierCreateSerializer
    authentication_classes = [CognitoAuthentication]

    @swagger_auto_schema(
        request_body=TierCreateSerializer,
    )
    def post(self, request):
        tenant_id = get_tenant_id_from_email(request.user[0])
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

        plan_id = serializer.validated_data["plan_id"]
        tier_names = serializer.validated_data["tier_names"]

        created_tiers = []
        errors = []

        for tier_name in tier_names:
            tier_data = {"name": tier_name, "plan_id": plan_id, "tenant_id": tenant_id}
            tier_serializer = TierSerializer(data=tier_data)

            if tier_serializer.is_valid():
                tier = tier_serializer.save()
                update_package_details(sender=Tier, instance=tier, created=True)
                created_tiers.append(tier_serializer.data)
            else:
                errors.append(tier_serializer.errors)

        if errors:
            return ResponseBuilder.errors(
                message="Invalid data in the request",
                data=errors,
                status_code=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
            )

        return ResponseBuilder.success(
            message="Tiers created successfully",
            data=created_tiers,
            status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED,
        )
```

This is the signal

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Tier)
def update_package_details(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        plan_id = instance.plan_id_id
        tier_id = instance.id

        package_detail_exists = PackageDetail.objects.filter(package_id__plan_id=plan_id).exists()

        if package_detail_exists:
            package = PackageDetail.objects.filter(package_id__plan_id=plan_id).first()
            
            
            new_package_detail = PackageDetail.objects.create(
                package_id=package.package_id,
                tier_id=Tier.objects.get(id=tier_id),
                details={},  
                tenant_id=instance.tenant_id,
            )

            return new_package_detail if package_detail_exists else None
```

Now this runs successfully but instead it creates 2 instances/records with the same value.

I just want one value to be added in the db how do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

cuz you called signal handler function 'update_package_details' manually.

when model save is called, post_save is called internally. ([see this docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/signals/#post-save))

so, remove this line in post function

`update_package_details(sender=Tier, instance=tier, created=True)`

good luck!